# SQL Union and Merge Subset Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

```
T1
SCHOOL  STUDENT TEACHER 
1   1   A   
1   2   B   
1   3   B   
1   4   B   
                
        
T2          
SCHOOL  STUDENT TEACHER 
2   7   A   
2   6   A   
2   8   B   
2   9   B


        
T3          
SCHOOL  TEACHER ID  
1   A   FOX 
1   B   CAT 
2   A   DOG 
2   B   MOUSE   
        
        
        
T4  
SCHOOL  STUDENT TEACHER ID
1   1   A   FOX
1   2   B   CAT
1   3   B   CAT
1   4   B   CAT
2   7   A   DOG
2   6   A   DOG
2   8   B   MOUSE
2   9   B   MOUSE
```

I have T1 T2 T3 where I wish to UNION T1 and T2 and afterwards JOIN T3 such as:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION
(SELECT * FROM T2)
JOIN
(SELECT SCHOOL, TEACHER, ID
WHERE SCHOOL != 10
FROM T3)
```

BUT I receive error "UNEXPECTED JOIN"

Comment: You are using the ‘()’ the wrong way. And don’t forget to use ‘ON’ on JOIN statement

Comment: Either ```SELECT .. FROM (SELECT .. FROM t1 JOIN t3 ...) UNION SELECT .. FROM (SELECT .. FROM t2 JOIN t3 ...)``` or ```SELECT .. FROM (SELECT .. FROM t1 UNION SELECT .. FROM t2) JOIN (SELECT .. FROM t3)```. The former query is more fast. And use UNION ALL - this is more fast if there is no duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOIN is a part of a SELECT statement while UNION are not.

So, you need to make UNION as a part of a SELECT statement

```
select * from (
  SELECT * FROM T1
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM T2) q1
JOIN
(SELECT SCHOOL, TEACHER, ID
   FROM T3
  WHERE SCHOOL != 10) q2
on /* here goes JOIN condition you need, like q1.school = q2.school*/
```

Please note:

1. there is another syntax error in your example: FROM goes always after SELECT and before WHERE
2. UNION will append result and eliminate duplicate rows which can run slower than UNION ALL. The latter will not check whether there are duplicate rows. So, if you're sure there won't be any duplicates in the result or if it's irrelevant whether you get duplicates or not, you may use UNION ALL